# Google web designer, create and ads with remote feed

Tags: google-web-designer

I'm new to google web designer, and I'm trying to create a simple ads with content from a remote feed, this is work using dynamic properties of this tool , but how to do that with a hosted feed ?
any tuto or advice are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Is that a 3rd party feed, or is it coming from any Google Ads tool (ie DoubleClick Dynamic, or Adwords GPA feed)?

I assume the former.
In that case, what you can do is create a custom event.
From the event panel, listen for the Ads to be initialized. Add as a callback function the ajax call to your remote feed, and the logic to change elements in the Dom to reflect that changes.

Comment: that's  perfect to me, this what I will do , create an custom event with ajax call , parse json and update the html , I'm just wondering if there is any security restriction in this case?

Comment: it may happens, when you test locally that there is some sandbox issue. In that case you need to move the creative files into a webserver (even a local server is fine).  Once you upload the ads on the google stack, different product behave in different way. Usually is down to the publisher allowing 3rd parties call.  GoogleDisplayNetwork, doesn't allow any 3rd parties call, unless pre approved.  If on the other hand you are just creating an Ad that is not suppose to ending up in any specific adserver, you are good to go.  Please notice that the 3rd party server needs a crossdomain policy.

Comment: So google Ad-words do not accept third party , this what happen just now trying to test my creation on google ad network, how should I proceed with google adwords network ?

Comment: You need to talk with your account manager at Google regarding 3rd parties links. This is not a limitation of google web designer, but just the platform of the ad server (in this case google ad network)